# Jhipster project - error with ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor class in spring-boot app

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, jhipster

I just start a new Jhipster project on my computer.

I have install the Open JDK 11.0.6, the last version on node and npm (node 16.15.0).

I have created the project with jhipster to test it but I have some issues to launch the backend part with spring-boot in Intellij.

When I open my project in IntelliJ and launch the Spring boot app, I got this error:

java: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor' less than -source '11'

This error comes during the compilation of the application
I put below some screen of my configuration

[My java version in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5kyv.png)

[My java in PATH variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y35OP.png)

[Java set in project INTELLIJ as SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TypEG.png)

[Java for the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH5qo.png)

And to finish, before all this, a java 1.6 was install on the computer but I have cut all the way to call it (PATH & JAVA_HOME). I can't delete it totally because I'm not an administrator of my computer.

Thanks for the idea in advance,

Have a good day,

Comment: Are you sure it's due to java version and not javac version? How do you launch your app in IntelliJ using maven or using main class? Are you able to launch backend using maven in Command prompt (outside IntelliJ)? Which version of JHipster?

Comment: I'm not sure that is the java version or the javac.
I launch the app with the main class. I've tried to launch the app with Mvn and it work correctly but I need to debug this with the interface of IntelliJ.
My Jhipster version is 6.7.1

Comment: Why using a 2 years old version of JHipster? Anyway, using maven to launch the app does not prevent you from remote debugging it from IntelliJ, there are plenty of resources that explain how to do it. It's like debugging your app when it is deployed in a remote server.

Comment: I don't choose the version of Jhipster, this is the version that install my npm.

Ok thanks for the advice, I will work with maven the time to correct the spring-boot error

Comment: You can install whatever version of JHipster you want with npm and you don't have to be an administrator to do so because you can install jhipster locally in your project's folder using `npm install generator-jhipster` rather than globally using `-g` option. This is a good practice for any npm package, not only jhipster.